# TypeScript: Why is the same object cannot be assigned with the interface when defined but can be assigned when passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here I have a object and an interface, its shape is like this

```
interface OBJ {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const obj: OBJ = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", random: 1 };
```

Here clearly TS compiler would error on `'random' does not exist in type 'OBJ'.`

However if I have a function as this

```
const getNewObj = (obj: OBJ) => ({
  fullName: obj.firstName + obj.lastName,
  ...obj
});
```

then I pass `obj` into this function
`console.log(getNewObj(obj));`

There is no error. How come?

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-joliot-s4j93?file=/src/index.ts:289-318

Comment: `obj` is a type of `OBJ`, thus it has errors as `random` is not declared in `OBJ`. And `getNewObj` does not explicitly return a type of `OBJ`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Pls check [this article](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/freshness)

Comment: Well you told to TypeScript that `getNewObj` takes an argument of type `OBJ` but _you did not specify the type of its return value_ therefore it is perfectly normal there is no error. If you want to specify that `getNewObj` shour return an object of type `OBJ`, you should write `const getNewObj = (obj: OBJ): OBJ => { /*...*/ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript has this ***Strict object literal checking***. simply put for functions: if you pass an object reference (variable or constant) to the function, typescript will check if this object reference contains the keys required for your function. Nothing less, but will allow from more keys.
**Example of this**:

```
const getNewObj = (obj: OBJ) => ({
  fullName: obj.firstName + obj.lastName,
  ...obj
});

const obj1 = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", random: 1}
const obj2 = {lastName: "Smith", random: 1}

getNewObj(obj1); // This is good, eventhough property random is extra
getNewObj(obj2); // Error: property firstName is missing
```

On the other hand, if you pass your function an object (not an object reference), then typescript will type check that object and throws an error for missing **and** extra properties
**Example, with the same function:**

```
getNewObj({ firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" }) // good
getNewObj({ firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", random: 1 }) //'random' does not exist..
getNewObj({ lastName: "Smith" }) // Property 'firstName' is missing...
```

---

More detail on this *Strict object literal* can be found in [this gitbook](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/freshness)

Comment: Indeed. The checking difference for fresh literals is really there to prevent common errors in common API usage patterns. In other words, it would be sound to provide an object with more properties, but it leads to errors like `@Component({ tmplate: './template.html' })` where the caller misspells the name of an optional property.